# Spark dataframe convert all the columns into json format and then modify json structure

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Converted my dataframe into json using df.toJSON

After json conversion the schema looks like this :

```
root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

Whats the best way to make the current schema(i.e., all root level attributes; in this case the 'value' column) nested into a new root level json key ( called 'data' ) and add new attributes at root level. How to achieve this in scala.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code.

```
scala> df.toJSON.select(struct($"value").as("data")).printSchema
root
 |-- data: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```